# Can you use anchors ^ $ with ls?

Tags: grep, ls

Do anchors only work with grep or can it be used with other commands?

For example:

```
ls -l ^cat
```

Comment: This has a bit of an XY problem smell on it, and doesn't seem a very good question. You're not telling if you want to match filenames based on the strings they start or end with; or if you want to use `^` and `$` only and in particular (for some obscure reason); or if you want to match filenames based on regular expression patterns in general (they contain much more than just the `^` and `$` anchors). Or in other words, is the point the particular type of pattern, or just matching at start of filename.

Answer (score 18):

Regular expression anchors such as `^` and `$` are only parsed by tools which *implement* regular expressions.  `ls` is not such a tool, and so no, it cannot use them.  However any binary invoked from the shell can use shell globbing, which is a simpler, albeit less powerful, wildcard-based search mechanism.

For example, for a list of all files whose names start with cat:

```
$ ls cat* # lists all files with names which start with 'cat'
$ ls *dog # lists all files with names which end with 'dog'
$ ls d*y  # Lists all files which names which start with 'd' and end
            with 'y', e. g. 'donkey'
$ ls p?g  # Lists all files which start with 'p', have one additional
            character, and end with 'g', e. g. 'pig' and 'pug'
```

For globbing purposes, `*` means 'zero or more characters'; while `?` means 'precisely one character'.

Comment: Never try to use globbing with dd.

Comment: in other words: there's no need for anchors with shell globs, since the patterns are matched against the full file name in any case...

Comment: @Joshua Could you enumerate the reasons for a Bash newbie?

Comment: @Hashim: Because it goes dd if=filename of=filename and glob doesn't know about the =.

Answer (score 11):

The `/bin/ls`  program - just like any other program - doesn't deal with `*` patterns. **[Globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) is done by [unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)**, not by the programs they are running. Let me explain a bit.

The `ls` program (which has several implementations that are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), like the one from the GNU [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) package, so feel free to study its source code) [gets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35335248/841108) a sequence of strings (as second argument to *its* `main` function) which has been [*expanded*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) by your shell (often `bash`). This is not specific to `ls`, it is true for every program started by your shell (often by using your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))).

For example, in a directory containing `a.c`, `a.o`, `b.c`, `d.c`, `e.h`  files, the `ls *.c` command is expanded *by the shell* into `ls a.c b.c d.c` so (in that case) `ls` gets 4 arguments: the first (of index 0) is `ls`, the second (of index 1) is `a.c`  etc... , the 4<sup>th</sup> (of index 3) being `d.c`. So the `ls` program *never sees* `*.c` and the shell is [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-ing it with four arguments. That program argument expansion, done by your shell, is called [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). Read [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) and be aware of the role of the [`IFS` shell variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html).

<sup>(notice that in some cases, [startup](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) files like your `$HOME/.bashrc` might define `ls` as some [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases); then replace `ls` with `\ls` or `command ls` or `/bin/ls` to avoid such an alias expansion (the latter two also work for circumventing a `ls` redefined as a *function*))</sup>

A very useful trick to understand what expansion happens is first to use the [auto-completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete) features of your shell (e.g. with your <kbd>TAB</kbd> key), or to replace the command (in your case `ls`) with `echo`.

So what you really want is **a shell with extended globbing**. You can find several, and you can write your own shell to do it:

- [zsh](http://zsh.org/) has [extended globbing](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation)
- [scsh](https://scsh.net/) has very different expansion (you can code it in Scheme)
- Try also [es](http://hawkwind.cs.toronto.edu:8001/mlists/es.html) or [ksh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh93)
- or adapt an existing shell (most are free software, whose source code you can study) to fit your needs, or write your own one.

FWIW, [`sash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) is a very simple and small shell (a bit buggy) whose source code is easy to read.

With Posix shells like [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash), - and also with others, like [fish](https://fishshell.com/) - you can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), e.g. using [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) (or even some `ls` [piped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) into some `grep`, like `ls -l $(ls | grep '^foo')` which is a bit useless and won't work in some cases like filenames with spaces or newlines, since same as `ls -l foo*`).

Some commands do globbing with some (often [quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html)) argument or data, e.g. [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html); and you can write such programs, e.g. using [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) or [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html). BTW, you can use regular expressions (used by [grep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) etc...) too in your programs, with the [regex(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html) functions.

Notice that writing your own shell is a very interesting exercise that I strongly recommend doing once. You'll need to learn how to use [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), e.g. by reading some book like [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://richard.esplins.org/static/downloads/linux_book.pdf), and implement your own globbing. And understanding (with the help of [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)) what [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) are done by some shell is worthwhile too.

Actually if `ls ^cat` means to you list all files whose name starts with `cat` you could just type the `ls cat*` command to your shell.

BTW, I really prefer `zsh` as my *interactive* shell (because IMHO its autocompletion works better, and its extended expansion is really useful), but it is a matter of taste, so YMMV. But you could try it (and if you adopt it, change your login shell with [chsh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html)).

At last, I recommend avoiding spaces (and newlines and control characters and most punctuation) in your own file names (so just use Latin letters and digits, dot `.`, percent `%`, underscore `_`, plus `+`, non-initial dash `-` or tilde `~` ...), but when coding shell scripts for general use by others, think of file names with spaces and weird characters. [Using `"$@"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12316565) in such scripts is then better.

<sup>PS. On Windows (which I don't know) things are rumored to be different, and globbing would be done by some startup code à la [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) or maybe in your `main`. You could read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to get some broader view.</sup>

Comment: Even worse, `ls -l $(ls |grep ^foo)` will fail if a selected filename contains an IFS character (by default SP HT NL) and may fail if a selected filename contains a glob char (`? * [..]` and sometimes others depending on shell, unless `set -f` or `set -o noglob`); `ls -l foo*` is safe in those cases. (Both fail if the expanded list exceeds maxargs -- unless `ls` is builtin which it could be.) And _a few_ programs do their own patterns or regexps, which often must be quoted to get past the shell: `find grep sed awk perl` et cetera.

Comment: FWIW, ksh93 globs can use regexps, So you can do: `ls -d ~(E)^foo` for instance (E for ERE, P for perl-like RE, G for BRE, X for _augmented_ RE).

Comment: Might be worth noting that  in `zsh -o extendedglob`, `ls ^foo` is passing all non-hidden file name except `foo` to `ls` (`^` is a _not_ glob operator) while in the Bourne shell `ls ^foo` would be the same as `ls | foo` (`^` was the pipe operator before that changed to `|`) and in `fish`, that's `ls 2> foo` (`^` redirects stderr).

Comment: With the `ast-open` implementation of `ls`, you can use the same patterns as in ksh93 globs for its `--ignore` option, so you can do `ls --ignore='~(E)^foo'`

Answer (score 5):

As others have explained, `ls` does not provide support for regular expressions. However, it is possible to list files matching a certain regular expression with GNU `find`, as I demonstrate below.

First, you can use the `ls` action:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -regex "ANY_REGEX" -ls
```

You could also use the `-exec` action, which allows you to use any  command:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -regex "ANY_REGEX" -exec ls -la {} \+
```

Finally, you could combine `find` with `xargs`, e.g. like this:

```
find * -regex "ANY_REGEX" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -la
```

By default, `find` will search all subdirectories, which is why, to replicate the behaviour of `ls`, I have added the filter `-maxdepth 0`.

The action `-print0` of `find` and the option `-0` of `xargs` in the last example are necessary to handle file names that contain spaces. Thanks to @ilkkachu for pointing it out.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/214002)

Comment: I would argue that it does, at least partly. The second bit of the question is: can it be used with other commands? My answer shows that yes, it can be used with `find`. But I agree that it was not very complete. Thank you for the feedback anyway.

Comment: Your last `xargs` command has bugs with files containing whitespace

Comment: does it? It seems to work fine on my computer...

Comment: @Rastapopoulos, not files containing whitespace, but file _names_ containing whitespace. Try `touch "foo bar" ; find -name 'foo*' | xargs ls -l` . That's what `find -print0 | xargs -0` is for (or just use `find -exec ...`). Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Comment: Oh, you're right actually. I had tested pretty much exactly that, but had messed up my regular expression, so find returned nothing and `ls -l` got executed without argument. Thank you very much! I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

These anchors are parts of a regular expression, so you can expect to use them in applications where regex is supported. You're standard bash shell globbing doesn't use regex, so `ls -l ^cat` will not work.

Answer (score -2):

You can use regular expressions "with" `ls`, but you have to pass them to `grep`.

```
ls | grep ^cat | xargs -r ls -l
```

The Bash supports regular expressions only by the comparison operator `=~`, which requires an `if` clause and a `for` loop.

```
for x in *; do if [[ "$x" =~ ^cat ]]; then ls -l "$x"; fi; done
```

Comment: that's horribly complex and breaks down if any filenames contain whitespace

Comment: @ilkkachu when this is already horribly complex, the solution for files with spaces will make you really happy: `ls | grep ^cat | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -r ls -l`.

Comment: or just use `ls -l cat*` ...

Comment: @ilkkachu I can not find any regular expression in your example.

Comment: so, just use the correct tool for the job.

Comment: @ilkkachu The question was not "what is the right tool" the question was "how to use a regular expression to filter files".

Comment: You'll note that the words "regular expression" don't appear in the question. At all.

Comment: @ilkkachu And how would you call this string `^cat`, if it is used as an argument to `grep`? Btw: I wish this site would have an ignore list.

Comment: the point is that without input from the user posing the question, we can't know if they specifically want to use a regex; or if they're looking for a way to do a pattern match at the start of the string in general.