# How to `unshare -n` without changing to root?

Tags: namespace, unshare

I'd like to run a shell that behaves exactly like the parent but without network. Why do I have to `su <login>` after `unshare`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised you can still `su user`, afaik after Linux kernel 3.19 the `su` command can become confused.

The unshare command isn't flexible enough to do it: it allows only a mapping to root. You have to map to yourself, after [`unshare`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/unshare.2.en.html), but before any fork/exec by writing `"<user> <user> 1"` to `/proc/self/uid_map` (and same for `/proc/self/gid_map`). All recent kernels also require to write first `deny` to `/proc/$$/setgroups`: all supplementary groups (eg: video) will have to be lost, this is unavoidable, like with `unshare -U/-r`.

Here's a *very simple* C program as proof of concept only, which doesn't do any checks to just do what you asked, but only if run by an user with uid/gid 1000/1000: lose network. Feel free to improve it.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd;

    unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER|CLONE_NEWNET);
    fd=open("/proc/self/setgroups",O_WRONLY);
    write(fd,"deny",4);
    close(fd);
    fd=open("/proc/self/uid_map",O_WRONLY);
    write(fd,"1000 1000 1",11);
    close(fd);
    fd=open("/proc/self/gid_map",O_WRONLY);
    write(fd,"1000 1000 1",11);
    close(fd);
    execvp(argv[1],argv+1);
}
```

If the file is called `removenet.c`, compile it with `gcc -o removenet removenet.c`.

```
$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),44(video)
$ ip -br a
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
eth0@if11        UP             10.0.3.66/24 fe80::216:3eff:fe6a:c1e9/64 
$ ./removenet bash
$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),65534(nogroup)
$ ip -br a
lo               DOWN
```

Note also that the new network namespace has its `lo` interface starting down, and since you're not root, you can't even set it up.

You can run variants of this program to revert to your former user *after* becoming root with eg `unshare -r -n -m`, by changing *again* into a new user namespace. This allows to set up some environment first, like mounting `/sys` to not see the former interfaces there, bringing the `lo` interface up, etc. See my answer to a similar question there (with the same code, you just have to add again `|CLONE_NEWNET`):

[unshare --map-root-user switch to original uid/username after setup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440177/unshare-map-root-user-switch-to-original-uid-username-after-setup/457419#457419)

To be clear: I don't know of any standard utility that exists able to do what you're asking with a simple shell command. So you have to resort to use an other language than shell: C, python, ... there's even [ctypes.sh foreign function interface for bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402834/execute-system-calls-directly/402847#402847).

This other answer of mine gives also some additional informations and an other "language", the gdb debugger:

[how to unshare network for current process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457117/how-to-unshare-network-for-current-process/457321#457321)

Comment: Turns out newer versions of `unshare` can do it: `unshare -U --map-user=$(id -u) --map-group=$(id -g) -n` (the group part silently sets `--setgroups=deny` which should not be given again else this would trigger an error).